# Poppler is installed: why do I get an error using pdf2image on python3?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew, poppler

I am using python `3.7.4` on a macOS 10.14.6 and I am trying to use `pdf2image` to convert a pdf file into an image. So I have installed `poppler` with `Homebrew`. I get an error message when I try to convert the PDF.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 240, in _page_count
    proc = Popen(command, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdfinfo': 'pdfinfo'
```

I use the following code:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
from pdf2image.exceptions import (
    PDFInfoNotInstalledError,
    PDFPageCountError,
    PDFSyntaxError
)

images = convert_from_path('test.pdf')
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michelebutturini/Desktop/Segmentation.py", line 16, in <module>
    images = convert_from_path('test.pdf')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 54, in convert_from_path
    page_count = _page_count(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 244, in _page_count
    raise PDFInfoNotInstalledError('Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?')
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
```

Comment: `Is poppler installed and in PATH?` - do you have setup your `PATH` correctly?

Comment: Hi Kampi,
this is the PATH:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

and this is were poppler is:

/usr/local/Cellar/poppler/0.79.0

How do I know if my PATH is correctly set up?

Thanks

Comment: try installing "poppler-utils" which is used by the poppler internally to get the count for the number of pages in the pdf.

Answer (score 7):

I've had this problem on **Google Colab** and I've fixed with this command:

```
!apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and found my answer here:
https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image/issues/101

What SamikhaAgarwal said was:

> "These pdf2image and pdftotext library backend requirement is Poppler, so you have to install

```
conda install -c conda-forge poppler
```

> Then the error will be resolved, and if still it doesn't work for you, then you can follow http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/ to install this library.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
brew install poppler
```

This worked for me.